# GoogleApiClient and GooglePlayServicesClient: Can you preserve a separation of concerns?

Tags: android, google-play-services, separation-of-concerns, google-api-client, location-client

My Situation:

1. First, I implemented Google Plus authentication in my app. I followed the [quick start instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) and added the [quick start sample app code](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android) to my app.
2. Then I wanted to obtain the user's last known location. The Fused Location Provider appeared to be the most modern way of obtaining it, so I looked at [LocationUpdates.zip](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and [kpbird's demo code](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html).

My Concern:

- The `com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient` and `com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient` namespaces introduce some overlap by virtue of the fact that if you want to use `GoogleApiClient` and `LocationClient`, then your class (i.e. `Activity`) must implement the following:

  ```
  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,  
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,  
  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,  
  GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
  ```

And code from **both** namespaces will override the following:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            /* pseudo-code
            if (GoogleApiClient) {
               // Implementation
            } else {                
               // Must be LocationClient
            }
            */
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            /* pseudo-code
            if (GoogleApiClient) {
               // Implementation
            } else {                
               // Must be LocationClient
            }
            */
}
```

Such that you will be forced to write code to discern if it was the `GoogleApiClient` or the `LocationClient` that triggered the `onConnected` and the `onConnectionFailed` event handlers.

---

My Question:

- I'd like to preserve a [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734567/separating-the-concerns-of-activity-and-googleapiclient/31734568#31734568

It is not a complete solution to your problem, but may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of implements these interfaces in your activity class itself, you can create separate object members in your activity class.

```
public YourActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks apiClient1 = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        }
    };

    private GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener apiClient2 = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        }
    };

    private GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks servicesClient1 = new GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        }
    };

    private GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener servicesClient2 = new GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

And then, create your GoogleApiClient with

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(yourContext, apiClient1, apiClient2);
builder.addApi(...).addScope(...);
GoogleApiClient apiClient = builder.build();
```

create your LocationClient with

```
LocationClient locClient = new LocationClient(yourContent, servicesClient1, servicesClient2);
```